# How to replace a regular expression {{someText}} with some other text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input string:

```
var mystring = "{{myDog}} is a good dog"
```

OR

var mystring = "{{anotherDog}} is a good dog"

Now, using `replace` method, and a regular expression, i want to replace `"{{myDog}}"` `"{{anotherDog}}"`  or  with `"Tommy"`.

NOTE: I do NOT want to rely on the string within 2 sets of curly braces.. So, there can be anything between 2 curlybraces that along with curly braces should be replaced by Tommy.
So, `myString.replace('{{myDog}}', 'Tommy')` won't work.

So,

```
mystring.replace('**someregularexpressionhere**', 'Tommy');
"Tommy is a good dog" // this should be value returned.
```

How can I compose my regular expression?

Comment: In this example `mystring.replace('{{myDog}}', 'Tommy')` would suffice, unless it needs to be done multiple times. Why do you feel a regular expression is needed?

Comment: yes, but i dont want to rely on myDog, there can be any string between 2 curly braces

Comment: If you can assume them, take a look at _template strings_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written small template function, you can try it

```js
function tpl(str, data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
     str = str.replace(new RegExp('\{\{' + key + '\}\}'), data[key]);
    });
    
    return str;
}
                       
console.log(
    tpl('{{myDog}} is a good dog, {{anotherDog}}', { myDog: 'Tommy', anotherDog: 'Jim' })
);
```

**Update:**

```js
function tpl(str, data) {
    return str.replace(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g, function (match) {
        return data.shift() || match;
    });
}
                       
console.log(
    tpl('{{a}} is a good dog, {{b}}', ['Tommy', 'JIm'])
);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Sorry, but I do not want to rely on myDog and anotherDog string. In this  tpl('{{myDog}} is a good dog, {{anotherDog}}', { myDog: 'Tommy', anotherDog: 'Jim' }), we are still relying on those strings. What I want is something like this:
 tpl('{{blablhahdf}} is a good dog, {{someotherblahblahthatwedont know}}', { 'Tommy', 'Jim' })

Answer (score 1):

Building a *RegExp* which lets you call `.replace` once would look like this

```
function replaceTemplate(str, dict) {
    var re = RegExp('\\{\\{(' + Object.keys(dict).join('|') + ')\\}\\}', 'g');
    return str.replace(re, function (a, b) {
        return dict[b];
    });
}

var s = '{{foo}} is {{bar}}',
    d = {
        foo: 'long day',
        bar: 'long'
    };
replaceTemplate(s, d); // "long day is long"
```